# Percentage of the population taking antipsychotics by country and year

Tags: data-request, medical, demographics, database

I was wondering, for each country, and for the pay twenty or so years, what percentage of the population is on antipsychotics by country with diagnoses such as schizophrenia, bipolar disorder, personality disorder, or attention deficit hyperactivity disorder, and would like to know the percentage of adults and children, as well as average stay in hospital as a means of forced psychiatric confinement for each of these.